# Theme responsible for CircularProgressIndicator

Tags: flutter, widget, flutter-layout

I want to give every CircularProgressIndicator a color in my app but what attribute is responsible for it in MaterialApp widget:

```
MaterialApp(
   theme: ThemeData(
     // what is the attribute for this widget.
  )
)
```

I used both accentColor and colorScheme.secondary but still not change.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `ThemeData` there is `progressIndicatorTheme` attribute which you can assign `ProgressIndicatorThemeData` constructor to it, and there you can change the default color of `ProgressIndicator`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `accentColor` to change the color of CircularProgressIndicator. It will look like this:

```dart
 theme: ThemeData(
         accentColor: Colors.red,
```

**EDIT:**

In the newest version of Flutter, you should use `colorScheme` instead of `accentColor`.

```
  colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch().copyWith(
    secondary: Colors.red, 
  ),
```

Comment: In the newest version of Flutter they deprecated accentColor.

Comment: @AraHussein I edited the answetr. Try this:

`colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch().copyWith(
    secondary: Colors.red, // Your accent color
  ),`